# add together 2 int vars with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm working on a send / resend email button for the backend of my website and currently am trying to work out how to add 2 integers that I have made vars.

The script works fine as long as the integers are not 0, could anyone give me some pointers? I need it to show the total regardless of whether 1 of the vars is 0, thanks in advance

```
function sendResend() {
    var selected = Array();
    var selectedSend = $(".no:checked").length;
    var selectedResend = $(".yes:checked").length;
    var totalSendResend = parseInt(selectedSend) + parseInt(selectedSend);
        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
        });
        var answer = confirm('You have selected ' + totalSendResend + ' emails. ' + selectedSend + ' New emails will be sent & ' + selectedResend + ' will be resent. Are you sure you want to continue?');
        if (answer) {
            alert(selected);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, you don't need to parseInt on .length, it's already int. also the 2nd parseInt(selectedSend); shouldn't be parseInt(selectedResend);?

Comment: Never use `parseInt` without the second parameter. Set it to 10. So it should read `parseInt(selectedSend, 10)`. Otherwise Javascript will act in a strange way in certain circumstances and you will spend a lifetime tracking down the bug :). (not the source of the problem in this case I suspect)

Comment: Why are you trying to `parseInt()` an `int`?

Comment: @bažmegakapa good advice. ParseInt treats any number with a leading zero as octal (base 8) unless you supply the radix parameter.

Comment: Also, you should either create an array with `new Array()` or simply `[]`. `Array()` is not enough.

Comment: @bažmegakapa wrong. `Array()` and `new Array()` behave identically. You should use `[]`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Good to learn something new every day :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa `Array(int)` or `new Array(int)` is only useful if you want to avoid re-allocation or over-allocation of a performance-critical fixed-length array or in cases like `Array(100).map(function(){return Math.random()})`. Any other signature can (and should) be replaced with an array literal.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yep, in most cases I use the literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:

```
var totalSendResend = parseInt(selectedSend) + parseInt(selectedSend);
```

That adds the same values together; you wanted this:

```
var totalSendResend = selectedSend + selectedResend;
```

You didn't need the `parseInt()` cast at all, but if you did, you should always specify the radix as the second parameter, e.g. `parseInt('0123', 10)`

Answer (score -1):

When you call `ParseInt(myvalue)` and `myvalue` begins with 0, it returns you an int considering value is expressed in octal.

To avoid this behavior always use `parseInt(value, 10);`

Edit : More info on how parseInt works no radix is specified :

- If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed.
- If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.  For this reason always specify a radix when using parseInt.
- If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).

See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Not really an answer to this question.

Comment: Considering his code works "as long as the integers are not 0" it may be

Comment: @Sylv21 `0` parses just fine. It's just numbers that start with `0` that cause trouble with `parseInt`

Comment: Ok I answer too quickly, mea culpa ! However it's always a bad idea to use ParseInt without radix ;)

Comment: Thanks guys, thats a very stupid mistake for me to have made, all works now and I am not using parseInt